# ViewController segue and login

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Swift (and programming in general). I'm having some difficulties in Xcode with the login feature. What I want is that the user should be logged in if no errors was returned and the user should be sent to another controller. I've read some of the documentation from Apple and the `performSegueWithIdentifier` (and of course some questions asked here), but it still does not work when I use a segue with `push` or `modal` that are given an identifier. Either the app crashes, or the user is sent to my `UITabBarController` even if the credentials was incorrect.

This is my LogInViewController.swift:

```
@IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject)
{
    if self.emailField.text == "" || self.passwordField.text == ""
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Please enter an email and password.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(self.emailField.text!, password: self.passwordField.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error == nil
            {
                self.emailField.text = ""
                self.passwordField.text = ""
            }
            else
            {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)

              let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
             // User Logged in
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoggedIn", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get in the console:

> 2016-09-04 14:55:30.019 DrinkApp[37777:1006336] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'LoggedIn'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Firebase login example:

```
  func login() {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(textFieldLoginEmail.text!, password: textFieldLoginPassword.text!) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "User Authentication error",
                                              message: error?.localizedDescription,
                                              preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                                             style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                }
                let resetPasswordAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                                                        style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                }
                alert.addAction(OKAction)
                guard let errorCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: (error?.code)!) else { return }
                switch errorCode {
                case .ErrorCodeWrongPassword:
                    alert.addAction(resetPasswordAction)
                case .ErrorCodeNetworkError:
                    print("Network error")
                default:
                    print("Other error\n")
                    break
                }
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else { // User Logged in
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MySegue", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
```

I only handled two errors for this example.

If you use `push segue`, you need to have navigation controller, and your `root segue` should lead to the `login view controller`, then another `segue` to the next view controller. This last `segue` must have an identifier (in this case it's `MySegue`)

**Edit:**
Since it seems that your problem is not with `Firebase`, but with setting up the storyboard. Here is an example:

1. Set up one `UINavigationController` two `UIViewControllers`
2. <kbd>Control</kbd> Drag between the `UINavigationController` to the middle `UIViewControllers` and choose `root view controller` from the popup menu
3. <kbd>Control</kbd> Drag between the `UIViewController` to the last `UIViewControllers` and choose `show`
4. select the segue added in the previous step and change its identifier (in the attributes inspector) to MySegue. 
   5.Choose the Middle `UIViewControllers` and change the class name (in the identity inspector) to your login view controller class.

Here is the full setup:
[image: full setup]

control drag menu (step 2):

[image: step 2]

Segue attributes inspector (step 4):

[image: step4]

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get it. I've added the performSegueWithIdentifier:

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
// User Logged in
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoggedIn", sender: self)
But I get this in the console: 
2016-09-04 14:20:56.968 DrinkApp[35936:985848] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'LoggedIn'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Comment: it looks like you have 2 navigation controllers.

Answer (score 4):

There are two main ways to send a user to another View Controller. The first is **performSegueWithIdentifier**. Here's how you would go about using that:

> First of all, control-drag from the yellow circle of the original VC to the target VC in the interface builder.

[image: The Yellow Circle]

Next, click on the 'segue arrow' that appears between the two View Controllers.

[image: the arrow]

In the *identifier* field, type in **mySegue**.

[image: here]

Next, go back to your code. When you reach the sign in section, add the following code:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: nil)
```

The second method is a bit more advanced. Here's how that would work:

> First, click on the yellow circle of the destination VC. Click on the newspaper, then call the *storyboard ID* **myVC**.
>
> Make sure to click on **Storyboard ID**

[image: here]

Go back to the same part of the code and copy and paste this code:

```
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initViewController: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myVC") as UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(initViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment down below if you have any questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer mentioned here to be super elegant.
https://fluffy.es/how-to-transition-from-login-screen-to-tab-bar-controller/

it works with tab bars, and nav bars. you create a function in the scene delegate, that switches the root view controller. you access the scene delgates functions and windows with `(UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?`